# Using my previous desktop computer as custom ubuntu router, will throughput be high?

Tags: ubuntu, router, firewall, iptables, gateway

I'm going to be redoing my home network soon and am thinking of using a dedicated ubuntu machine to use as the router/firewall as well as being a web server, nas (media file server), dns, wifi, and just a general complete server box. The machine i have now has a dual core 2.5ghz processor with 3 gigs of ram and two gigabit NICs. What kind of throughput should i expect? Will it be as good as say an Asus Black Diamond router (known to be the one of the fastest consumer routers regarding throughput), or should i just buy a black diamond to handle routing and use the server for everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Will you relay on a modem, router, pci card for Wan ?

Depending on the usage from other services you are not supposed to have problems with traffic...

If you try to get data from share on your nas, and the same time try to get something from the internet in an another computer you will propably have problem on the internet.

It is better to have Services in seperate System than Gateway and for sure... alot more secure.